# How to find out what Graphics Card is present in your system?

Tags: hardware, graphics

Is it possible to find the exact configuration and model of your systems graphics card in Ubuntu 10.10?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out the model of my graphics card?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72766/how-do-i-find-out-the-model-of-my-graphics-card)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The quickest (non-graphical) way to this is to run `lspci | grep VGA` in a terminal.

If you want you can also install [hardinfo](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hardinfo) [image: Install hardinfo]
 on your system, and when you launch it (system benchmark and profiler in the system menu), you can find your graphics information easily.

[image: Example]

See this image for an example.

Comment: Hi Roland, I have edited out a broken image link (cf. [the previous version](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/12783/4)). It's maybe worth going over your old posts and seeing which other bit.ly links have rotted?

Comment: @E.P. There are a lot of them. If you want to edit them, replace with `http://hostmar.co/software-small` (or `http://hostmar.co/software-large` or `http://hostmar.co/software-banner` as appropriate). See http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1853/158442 and http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/395/158442

Comment: The problem with lspci is that, it does not show the integrated graphics card! I have one enabled but it wont show up on lspci results! the funny thing is I am using both at  the moment!

Answer (score 46):

Use

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G73 [GeForce 7600 GT]
       vendor: nVidia Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:fc000000-fcffffff ioport:8c00(size=128) memory:fe7e0000-fe7fffff
```

Answer (score 5):

`$sudo inxi -F -x`
(case sensitive) Will give a nice summary of your system, easy to read. Use the switch -G for just graphics. But it doesn't show video RAM, though one should be able to google the reported graphics for what it 'should' have. I also like the graphical 'hardinfo' which summarizes hwinfo (I think)  will give more but still doesn't report graphics memory that I can see

`$sudo dmesg |grep VRAM`  will show how much video ram you have.

Also

```
glxinfo -B
```

lspci, lshw, hwinfo seem to just report the prefetch (often 512mb) or reports each module in hex format