# How do I get apt links to work with Google Chrome

Tags: apt, google-chrome

I was reading another [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12780/how-to-find-out-what-graphics-card-is-present-in-your-system) on ask-ubuntu, where I encountered an apt link. Intrigued, I clicked on it, expecting my browser to launch the software center, only to get a page saying "You don't seem to be running Ubuntu".

Browser: Google Chrome 12.0.742.0 dev

the link I clicked on apt.ubuntu.com/p/hardinfo

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That seems odd. When I click on an apt-link, I get a request from Google Chrome to run `xdg-open apt:packagename`. Doing so then asks me whether I want to install said package. (Same Chrome version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to use Chromium not Chrome. This is because Chrome doesn't include *Ubuntu* in it's useragent but Chromium does.

The easiest way to do this and keep the dev channel, [is to use the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/dev).

Of course this isn't ideal, hopefully in the near future a new version of apt.ubuntu.com will be released that works with Chrome.

Comment: fluteflute, thanks for the clarification. I will stick with Google chrome for now, but at least I understand the problem. Thanks again

Comment: I would use Chromium if the tabs didn't make my system crash when I try to splice them into their own window. Google-chrome doesn't crash, or crash the entire system. :|