# How do I find out the model of my graphics card?

Tags: graphics, hardware, gpu

I would like to know the model of my graphics card. I think it may be an ATI, but I want to be sure!

I have Ubuntu 11.10 (32 bit) and an Asus A6 VA laptop.

Comment: The best answer that I have found so far is here: http://askubuntu.com/a/392944/173666

Comment: This answer is the one that helped me most: http://askubuntu.com/a/5420/21035

Answer (score 330):

Open up "Terminal", and type: `lspci | grep VGA`

There, you'll find your GPU card's model.

Comment: I had to specify -v (verbose) to get the model on my ATI... `for s in $(lspci | grep VGA | awk '{print $1}'); do lspci -v -s $s; done`

Comment: In such cases, `DeviceName` is what you want and it's likely the line after the one you're grepping.

Use `lspci -v | grep VGA -A 1` to include one line after.

Comment: First do `sudo update-pciids` to download new version of the PCI ID list. Then do `lspci`. Updating pci ids can improve information available as `lspci` output.  
For example, before updating pci ids, _01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM (rev a2)_  
Compare that to after doing update-pciids, _01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM **[Quadro M1200 Mobile]** (rev a2)_

Comment: Good shot, but which of [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 ... ] :)
?

Comment: Looks like it works not for all cases, for some configurations I get:
`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GV102 (rev a1)`

Comment: This did not work for me, it only listed the motherboards graphics, and not the dedicated graphics chip of my laptop

Comment: In my case, this command can't catch the Nvidia drive since it is `05:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce MX450] (rev a1)`

Answer (score 154):

For detailed information about your graphics card, usually including its make and model, run:

```
sudo lshw -C video
```

This *might* give the make and model name more often than `lspci`, but it is not *guaranteed* to give it (nor is `lspci`).

`sudo lshw -C display` is equivalent.

You can run this (either one) without `sudo`, but you're a little less likely to get as much information. Still, `lshw -C video` is a reasonable choice if you don't have administrative powers.

If you like, you can parse the output to get just the line with the model name:

```
sudo lshw -C video | grep product:
```

Or if you need to extract just the name (for example, for scripting purposes--but remember there isn't always anything to extract):

```
sudo lshw -C video | awk -F'product: ' '/product/{print $2}'
```

(Don't forget the space just after `-Fproduct:`, before the closing `'`.)

As an example: on my system, this gives:

```
M52 [Mobility Radeon X1300]
```

Comment: first command worked pretty well for AMD gpu

Comment: lspci gives Intel only but this command gives both Nvidia and Intel on my computer. However, the model information is still absent. The result is solely "Intel Corporation           
NVIDIA Corporation". From settings I see it is "NVIDIA Corporation / NVIDIA GeForce MX450"

Comment: I understand why I can't see the complete video card information. We should update the PCI hardware database that Linux maintains by entering "update-pciids".

Answer (score 38):

Sometimes lspci is not enough:

```
$ lspci -nn |egrep "VGA|Display"
```

e.g.: you can end up with something like this:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2e32] (rev 03)
```

so then you can try to grep Xorg log:

```
$ grep -i chipset /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

and dmesg

```
$ dmesg |grep -i agp
```

Comment: The `Xorg` logs were the only thing that had the specific model for me. +1

Comment: +1 Having an Intel card, only this method gives me some specific info about my card.

Answer (score 12):

1. run gnome-control-center (from a terminal, or in the main menu system settings)
2. search for 'system' and open "System Info"
3. You are done.

Comment: Type update-pciids and then try lspci again

Comment: All the terminal solutions found here showed me only '3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller'.  This GUI solution showed me the real id, 'Intel® Ivybridge Mobile'.  For once, the GUI solution offered more.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

If GUI/display available, you can try:

```
xrandr --listproviders
```

Comment: I have a Radeon RX480 and all the other answers were giving me outputs that didn't have the exact model number. Thanks @Constantine!

Comment: ONLY this answer gives me the exact model of my GPU

Answer (score 4):

(Other answers where either only giving a chipset range or no manufacturer info for my AMD card.)

To get exact chipset model, video memory, and drivers info:

```
glxinfo -B
```

To get card manufacturer name:

```
hwinfo --gfxcard | grep SubVendor
```

Comment: +1 for the hwinfo command showing the manufacturer:)

Answer (score 4):

**Ubuntu 20.04 Settings -> About**

You can either open settings by clicking as mentioned at: https://askubuntu.com/a/1144742/52975 but I just do:

- Super key (AKA Windows key)
- Type "about" and select the entry

So under "Graphics" I can see that my GPU model is "Quadro M1200/PCIe/SSE2".

[image]

**nvidia-settings**

Mixes runtime with some static info.

[image]

More details: [How do I check if Ubuntu is using my NVIDIA graphics card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68028/how-do-i-check-if-ubuntu-is-using-my-nvidia-graphics-card/692412#692412)

Answer (score 1):

In KDE you can use the `kinfocenter` (open a command prompt from a graphical environment and type that, or type it at the K-menu [application menu] prompt; or navigate to K → Computer → Info Center ... ).

Personally I use lshw or lspci as in other answers, but another possibility is :

`glxinfo | grep Device`

Which maybe only works if your device is using OpenGL, not sure, but for me this gives:

```
    Device: AMD KAVERI (DRM 3.27.0, 5.0.0-15-generic, LLVM 8.0.0) (0x1313)
```

which is quite neat. The second number is the kernel version, fwiw.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect your graphic card from Ubuntu Desktop, try this:

1. Click on User menu at the top right corner on the top Menu bar
2. Select System Settings
3. Click on Details.
4. By default you should see your graphic information. Take look at this [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67aLc.png).

Note: This answer was done in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version.

Answer (score 0):

The command line tool called `inxi` will show You:

```
inxi -Gx
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nvidia v: 435.21 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.5 driver: nvidia resolution: 3440x1440~75Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1080/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 435.21 direct render: Yes
```

Install it from Github : https://github.com/smxi/inxi or using Apt:

```
sudo apt install inxi
```

Answer (score 0):

If `nvidia-smi` is already installed on the system then try running `nvidia-smi -L`. It's kinda straightforward.

For example:

```
$ nvidia-smi -L
GPU 0: NVIDIA GeForce GTX xxxx with Max-Q Design (UUID: ...)
```

As per the help file (`nvidia-smi --help`):

```
  LIST OPTIONS:

    -L,   --list-gpus           Display a list of GPUs connected to the system.
```