# How to make OpenCL work on 14.10 + Nvidia 331.89 drivers?

Tags: nvidia, opencl

Proprietary drivers 331.89 do not give me OpenCL.  (tried both tested/updates)
for a while I had version 304.123   that worked - except I wanted the current drivers, and now are unable to downgrade.

Anyway - I could downgrade by workaround, but I wish 331.89 worked.

I used "darktable -d opencl" as test
alos added symbolic link to darktable, but that does not help with 331.89

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I too was confounded by this perplexing problem until I found a series of [forum posts bout Virtual Lighttable](http://sourceforge.net/p/darktable/mailman/darktable-users/thread/CANz0AchwpTTZB0mRtFiyY-uj-XcNnwNk3HyQ9ugb_wL3DdejBA%40mail.gmail.com/#msg32641742) in which the participants do some debugging. It turns out that the NVIDIA drivers need a custom modprobe rule that is not installed by default with either `nvidia-331` or the the opencl drivers. These rules are provided in the `nvidia-modprobe` package.

Here is a list of all of the packages you will need to get OpenCL working on Ubuntu 14.10 with NVIDIA drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-331-uvm nvidia-opencl-dev nvidia-modprobe
```

EDIT: In case anyone encounters a similar problem on Ubuntu 15.04 and the NVIDIA 346.59 drivers, the command to fix the issue is nearly identical:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-346-uvm nvidia-opencl-dev nvidia-modprobe
```

Comment: On Linux mint I encounter this error when running the `deviceQuery` CUDA test program: `optirun --bridge primus ./deviceQuery`
`./deviceQuery Starting...`

 `CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)`

`cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38`
`-> no CUDA-capable device is detected`
`Result = FAIL`

Answer (score 3):

**Ubuntu 20.04 install**

Things got much better now. Find available driver versions:

```
apt-cache search nvidia-driver
```

Install the latest one listed + opencl:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-435 nvidia-opencl-dev
```

You can also search under:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

in the "Additional Drivers" tab for the latest driver.

**Ubuntu 15.10 install**

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-352-dev nvidia-prime nvidia-modprobe nvidia-opencl-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/include/nvidia-352/GL /usr/local/include
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libOpenCL.so
```

**Test it out**

Compile and run:

```
gcc -o main main.c -lOpenCL
./main
```

Here's a minimal test program:

main.c

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <CL/cl.h>

int main() {
    cl_command_queue command_queue;
    cl_context context;
    cl_device_id device;
    cl_int input = 1;
    cl_int kernel_result = 0;
    cl_kernel kernel;
    cl_mem buffer;
    cl_platform_id platform;
    cl_program program;
    const char *source = "__kernel void increment(int in, __global int* out) { out[0] = in + 1; }";

    clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
    clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1, &device, NULL);
    context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, 0, NULL);
    buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_int), NULL, NULL);
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, &source, NULL, NULL);
    clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, "", NULL, NULL);
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "increment", NULL);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_int), &input);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &buffer);
    clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel, 0, NULL, NULL);
    clFlush(command_queue);
    clFinish(command_queue);
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof (cl_int), &kernel_result, 0, NULL, NULL);

    assert(kernel_result == 2);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/39fed9227337d414a12822345d2fa98535f34599/opencl/min.c).

**Notes**

- find your GPU model: [How do I find out the model of my graphics card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72766/how-do-i-find-out-the-model-of-my-graphics-card)
- test that the driver is working: [How do I check if Ubuntu is using my NVIDIA graphics card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68028/how-do-i-check-if-ubuntu-is-using-my-nvidia-graphics-card)
- do not install the `nvidia-current` package. It is old. Either `apt-cache search nvidia` and get the latest one, or use `software-properties-gtk` "Additional Drivers" tab.

I really recommend upgrading to 15.10 to get this to work: I had never managed before.

Tested on:

- Lenovo ThinkPad T430 with NVIDIA NVS 5400M
- Lenovo ThinkPad W540 with NVIDIA Quadro K1100M
- Lenovo ThinkPad P51 with an NVIDIA Quadro M1200 + Ubuntu 21.10 + driver `nvidia-driver-470`

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542808/how-to-compile-opencl-on-ubuntu/33483311#33483311

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 14.04 nvidia-modprobe messed up my system. But I realized that the **nvidia-331-uvm** is not activated from the start (god knows why). So let's activate it:

```
$ sudo modprobe nvidia-331-uvm
$ sudo mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia-uvm c 249 0
```

And then:

```
$ sudo clinfo
```

Then you'll be able to use opencl even as a non-root user. Why it's like this is explained in the [Virtual Lighttable mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/darktable/mailman/darktable-users/thread/CANz0AchwpTTZB0mRtFiyY-uj-XcNnwNk3HyQ9ugb_wL3DdejBA%40mail.gmail.com/#msg32641742).

Thus, I finally added the next lines in my `/etc/rc.local` file:

```
# begin opencl config
modprobe nvidia-331-uvm
mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia-uvm c 249 0
clinfo
# end opencl config
```

Then everything works smoothly ;)