# ubuntu 14.04 lts and nvidia graphic card

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics

I just bought a new laptop (LAPTOP DELL INSPIRON 5558 15.6'' INTEL CORE I3-4005U 4GB 500GB **NVIDIA GT920M** 2GB FREE DOS).
Since I am familiar with windows and have no idea of Ubuntu 14.04 lts I tried to learn them. My problem is that although I use the following command (`lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12`) on terminal, it does not show  me the name of the card. What do I have to do???
Also any good advise to begin studying about Ubuntu and understanding some things will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/72766/how-do-i-find-out-the-model-of-my-graphics-card

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First install the NVIDIA drivers.
Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Now see graphics information.
Open a terminal and execute :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

Update - addressing your comment that you did not install drivers but NVIDIA X Server Settings :

To make sure that you will have a clean and properly working graphics drivers installation on the laptop, uninstall every currently and maybe only partly installed NVIDIA drivers related software.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Install NVIDIA drivers and Optimus.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the `linux` line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter user name and password ... execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Now the output should read like this :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)  
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501  
Kernel driver in use: i915  

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)  
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501  
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: I have not yet install the drivers. I tried to see my graphics information and that's what I see on my terminal screen:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
 Subsystem: Dell Device 06ad
 Kernel driver in use: i915
--
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1299 (rev ff)
Also nvidia x server settings is already installed, does that mean that the drivers are installed too?

Answer (score 1):

- **To know your graphic card details :**

Open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>  and run this command:

```
`lspci -vnn | grep -i 3D -A 12`
```

To install the NVIDIA drivers run this command:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

- Now reboot your laptop with `sudo reboot` (or normal GUI method)
- As you asked, To learn about Ubuntu, I suggest you once Visit **[Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/)**  and  [**Ubuntu Guide**](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Trusty) where you can learn lot of things about Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu!... If this answer solved your problem, please do not forget to click the grey tick ☑ at the left of the answer to make it green, which means [Yes, this answer is valid !](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Oh come on! Adding third party PPAs? Use Additional drivers and be happy.