# Screen resolution 1280x1024@75 (Belinea 10 17 30) not working properly - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux. My old Belinea Monitor supports natively the following resolution:

https://www.cnet.com/products/belinea-10-17-30-lcd-monitor-17/specs/

https://gsd.eu/sales/img/datasheet/Belinea_101730.pdf

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. However Monitor resolution only 1024x768 detected.

Introduced a custom screen resolution according to this tutorial:
[How to set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)

Result is less desirable:

1. black stripe on top and bottom
2. circles look like eggs, heads look 'longish'
3. lower part of the desktop is cut (e.g the application selector on the lower right is not visible anymore)

Used this monitor before with Windows (worked flawless with this resolution)

I had to revert to 1024x768.

How to set it up properly?

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: This depends here on the graphics card of your machine. Which graphics card do you have ?

Comment: Some intel (it's a fanless mini-pc) - how to find out in ubuntu?

Comment: ~$ sudo lshw -C video | awk -F'product: ' '/product/{print $2}'
Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller

Comment: ~$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 35
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:121 memory:80000000-80ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

Comment: @dschinn1001 : Hope this helps, got this info from this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/72766/how-do-i-find-out-the-model-of-my-graphics-card

Comment: still open questions: - how to find out relevant infos of graphics card? - how to set monitor resolution properly?

Comment: Strange - I've put in a different 17" Monitor with same resolution - got detected and works fine. Anyone an Idea how to make the Belinea detected and run in 1280x1024 mode?