# Is There A Way To Fix These Graphical Bugs?

Tags: wine, games, steam

It's pretty self explanatory, but I'm having graphical issues with some of my games, where some things don't load properly. It's not just Windows games either, it's also native Linux games too, Psychonauts does this too GTA was just the game that I happened to have installed that did this, this is an old computer running Ubuntu 18.04 so that might be some of the issue, and again it's not just Windows games, it's also native games, but for some reason I don't get this same graphical issue with Sonic Adventure DX it plays normal(mostly)and I don't have any other problems that I can't live with, I mean, it doesn't completely effect game play other than what if I try driving somewhere, and I didn't see the wall because it didn't appear on my screen correctly, thank you for those willing to help and sorry this is long winded[image]

Comment: Please include in your question which graphics card is being used.

Answer (score 0):

If it is happening in both OS's, are you customizing your settings for the graphics? If you are not customizing your settings, perhaps there is a setting that is default creating your issue. Are you using generic or proprietary drivers? Try changing drivers. Perhaps it is a hardware issue. Overheating can result in almost random errors on LSI circuits and practically every chip ever made. Saying the computer is old doesn't tell us what you're packing. If there is no physics processor and the game needs one, that is asking for trouble off the bat.

Edit: Response to Comment: Open up software update and hit settings. pop open the tab for drivers and see if you are using proprietary drivers.

This thread shows you how to check what your graphics card is:

[How do I find out the model of my graphics card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72766/how-do-i-find-out-the-model-of-my-graphics-card)

Comment: I don't have Windows actually, and I don't know how to check all that stuff, I would install Windows and dual boot it but I screwed up the NTFS and I don't have a re-installation disc