installed Ubuntu 22.04 on HP-Pavilion Plus Laptop 14-ew1024nn problem with kernell panic sudo apt --fix-broken and graphics card drivers
I think I have a very complicated problem.
I don't have so much advanced knowledge about linux (Ubuntu 22.04).
I've installed it on HP Pavilion Plus Laptop 14-ew1024nn .
And when I was trying to solve some problems by myself and install graphic drivers for this notebook I steel have a problem with my device.
First of all I can use only:
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0.41-generic
Because when I run this version:
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0.44-generic
I'm getting this error:
Kernel panic - not syncing VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-bloc(0.0)
(...)

When im trying to remove this problematic Kernell:
"sudo apt-get purge linux-image-6.5.0-44-generic"

I will get this:
Reading package lists... Done
Building the dependency tree... Done
Reading status information... Done
You should run "apt --fix-broken install" to fix them.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl-dev : Violates dependencies: libegl-dev:i386 (!= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 libegl-dev:i386 : Violates dependencies: libegl-dev (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is supposed to be installed
 libegl1 : Requires: libglvnd0 (= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 Violates dependencies: libegl1:i386 (!= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 libegl1:i386 : Requires: libglvnd0:i386 (= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is to be installed
 Violates dependencies: libegl1 (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is supposed to be installed
 libgl-dev : Requires: libgl1 (= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 Violates dependencies: libgl-dev:i386 (!= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 libgl-dev:i386 : Requires: libgl1:i386 (= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is to be installed
 Violates dependencies: libgl-dev (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is supposed to be installed
 libgl1 : Requires: libglx0 (= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is to be installed
 Violates dependencies: libgl1:i386 (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is to be installed
 libgl1:i386 : Requires: libglx0:i386 (= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 Violates dependencies: libgl1 (!= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 libgles-dev : Violates dependencies: libgles-dev:i386 (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is supposed to be installed
 libgles-dev:i386 : Violates dependencies: libgles-dev (!= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 libgles1 : Violates dependencies: libgles1:i386 (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is to be installed
 libgles1:i386 : Violates dependencies: libgles1 (!= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 libgles2 : Violates dependencies: libgles2:i386 (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is to be installed
 libgles2:i386 : Violates dependencies: libgles2 (!= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 libglvnd-core-dev : Violates dependencies: libglvnd-core-dev:i386 (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is to be installed
 libglvnd-core-dev:i386 : Violates dependencies: libglvnd-core-dev (!= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 libglvnd-dev : Requires: libglvnd0 (= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 Requires: libglvnd-core-dev (= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 Violates dependencies: libglvnd-dev:i386 (!= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 libglvnd-dev:i386 : Requires: libglvnd0:i386 (= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is to be installed
 Requires: libglvnd-core-dev:i386 (= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is to be installed
 Violates dependencies: libglvnd-dev (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is supposed to be installed
 libglvnd0 : Violates dependencies: libglvnd0:i386 (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is to be installed
 libglvnd0:i386 : Violates dependencies: libglvnd0 (!= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 libglx-dev : Requires: libglx0 (= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is to be installed
 Violates dependencies: libglx-dev:i386 (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is supposed to be installed
 libglx-dev:i386 : Requires: libglx0:i386 (= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 Violates dependencies: libglx-dev (!= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is supposed to be installed
 libglx0 : Requires: libglvnd0 (= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 Violates dependencies: libglx0:i386 (!= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 libglx0:i386 : Requires: libglvnd0:i386 (= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is to be installed
 Violates dependencies: libglx0 (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is supposed to be installed
 libopengl-dev : Requires: libopengl0 (= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is to be installed
 Violates dependencies: libopengl-dev:i386 (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is supposed to be installed
 libopengl-dev:i386 : Requires: libopengl0:i386 (= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 Violates dependencies: libopengl-dev (!= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is supposed to be installed
 libopengl0 : Requires: libglvnd0 (= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 Violates dependencies: libopengl0:i386 (!= 1.4.0-1) but 1.7.0-2101~22.04 is to be installed
 libopengl0:i386 : Requires: libglvnd0:i386 (= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is to be installed
 Violates dependencies: libopengl0 (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) but 1.4.0-1 is supposed to be installed
 libvdpau1 : Violates dependencies: libvdpau1:i386 (!= 1.4-3build2) but 1.5-2105
 ~22/04 is to be installed
 libvdpau1:i386 : Violates dependencies: libvdpau1 (!= 1.5-2105~22.04) but 1.4-3build2 is supposed to be installed
 linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 : Requires: linux-image-6.5.0-44-generic but will not be installed

Secondly when I run on terminal:
 "sudo apt --fix-broken install"

I'm getting this response:
Reading package lists... Done
Building the dependency tree... Done
Reading status information... Done
Fixing dependencies... Done
The following packages were installed automatically and are no longer required:
 libgl1-amber-dri libgles2-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev:i386
To remove them, use "sudo apt autorove".
The following additional packages will be installed:
 libegl-dev libegl1 libgl-dev libgl1:i386 libgles-dev:i386 libgles1:i386 libgles2:i386 libglvnd-core-dev:i386 libglvnd-dev
 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-dev:i386 libglx0 libopengl-dev:i386 libopengl0 libvdpau1
The following packages will be updated:
 libegl-dev libegl1 libgl-dev libgl1:i386 libgles-dev:i386 libgles1:i386 libgles2:i386 libglvnd-core-dev:i386 libglvnd-dev
 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-dev:i386 libglx0 libopengl-dev:i386 libopengl0 libvdpau1
15 updated, 0 newly installed, 0 removed and 76 not updated.
21 not fully installed or removed.
Need to download 0 B/592 kB archives.
After this operation, an additional 19.5 kB of disk space will be used.
To continue? [Y/n]
(...)
Errors occurred while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AgywvE/00-libopengl-dev_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AgywvE/01-libopengl0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AgywvE/02-libglx-dev_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AgywvE/03-libgl-dev_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AgywvE/04-libgl1_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AgywvE/05-libglx0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AgywvE/06-libegl-dev_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AgywvE/07-libgles-dev_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AgywvE/08-libglvnd-dev_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AgywvE/09-libglvnd-core-dev_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AgywvE/10-libgles1_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AgywvE/11-libgles2_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AgywvE/12-libglvnd0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AgywvE/13-libegl1_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AgywvE/14-libvdpau1_1.5-2105~22.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

So I'm stuck for 2 weeeks and I don't know what should I do...
Please help me...
Thanks. Now I can use Linux 6.5.0.41-generic normally but still I cannot install my graphic drivers. In terminal when I type:
sudo lshw -C display
I'm getting this:
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 08
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:480-47f iomemory:400-3ff memory:4818000000-4818ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff memory:c0000-dffff memory:481a000000-4820ffffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 3
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=2880,1800

I solve problem with:
Because when I run this version:
**Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0.44-generic** 
    I'm getting this error:

**Kernel panic - not syncing VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-bloc(0.0)**
(...)

This video was very helpful:
To solve Kernel Panic
Also problems with "gpg NO_PUBKEY" I solved when I fixed path in PPA.
Now I'm trying to finally install graphic drivers.

Are you sure you can use Linux 6.5.0.41-generic, you can choose kernel in grub, and if you want you can also make grub to use that kernel. https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version

You need to get the name of your display card https://askubuntu.com/questions/72766/how-do-i-find-out-the-model-of-my-graphics-card
