# Lubuntu on ASUS 1215

Tags: lubuntu, performance, asus, ubuntu-netbook, eeepc

I have a ASUS Eee PC 1215P netbook (Seashell series) and liked to migrate from it's original MS-Windows 7 to Ubuntu/Lubuntu. There are documents on [Ubuntu official website](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201202-10625/) website which certifies that it's right with "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit". Somewhere else somebody mentioned that the performance of the system with that Ubuntu is very well and all hot keys works.

So I decided to try latest Lubuntu (14.10 edition, 32 bits) and it there was not any problem at the beginning. But the main problem is that the system works so slow that it is anoying. Moreover, most of hotkeys do not works.

Note that there is a hotkey (Fn+Space bar) which changes status of the netbook from Power Saver to High and Super High Performance -in MS-Windows, which it does not works in Lubuntu as well.

Firstly, how I can switch to config of high-performance? Secondly, is there any other reason which prevents reach to higher level of performance? Finally, how to activate all of hotkeys?

Thank you so much in forward.

P.S.: The configuration of the netbook due to [official website](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/Eee_PC_1215P/specifications/) is as the following:

**CPU**:  Intel® Atom™ N550 (Dual Core; 1.5GHz) Processor

**Memory**: DDR, 2 x SO-DIMM, 2GB

**Storage**: 2.5" SATA 250GB

**Wireless Data Network**: WLAN 802.11 b/g/n@2.4GHz

**Display**: 12.1" LED Backlight WXGA (1366x768) Screen

Note that without any application for comparing between origilan MS-Windows and Lubuntu systems performances, I feel the system had better performance with it's MS-Windows. Official website do not present any driver for linux based OS.

Comment: Try any alternate to gnome or ubuntu. Kubuntu, xubuntu, or lubuntu.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I am using **Lubuntu** as well.

Comment: What graphics card ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen That's an onboard Intel Graphic card but I do not have it's specifications. Just there had been written that this netbook has Graphics Acceleration.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/12780/how-to-find-out-what-graphics-card-is-present-in-your-system