# WiFi settings freeze and then won't open

Tags: networking, lenovo, freeze, settings

So I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 (Kernel 5.13.0-40-generic) on my Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3.
Now I'm experiencing my first real issue with it. I tried to connect to my university WiFi but not only does it not connect (even with correct username/password) but after trying to connect for a while it simply freezes the WiFi settings.
Everything else works perfectly but the settings window is completely frozen. I am still able to kill it with the "sudo xkill" command but afterwards whenever I try to open settings again it loads for a while and then nothing happens.
The only way to be able to open settings again is to restart the computer, but it still does not fix the issue that it does not connect to my university WiFi.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the graphics adapter?

Comment: @Pilot6 I am not sure what you mean by graphic adapter, the graphic card ? If yes then I found on this other forum (https://askubuntu.com/questions/12780/how-to-find-out-what-graphics-card-is-present-in-your-system) to type the following command: `lspci | grep VGA` and I get the following output:
`05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1638 (rev c5)`